# Point In Polygon using T-Sql

Tags: polygon

I am creating a mapping application which users can interactively draw a polygon on a Google Map.

I need to send this polygon data back to a Sql Server and determine which records to return based on their LatLng positions in the database being within the polygon.

Does anyone know how to do this or a routine that is available.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a geography column associated with your records, you can use that to query for items within  a polygon. [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) to get you started. Here's an example:

```
--What Items are within the Bermuda Triangle? 
---Note that Well-Known Text representation of a polygon is composed of points defined by Longitude then Latitude.
---Note that the points are defined in a counter-clockwise order so that the polygon is the interior of the triangle.  
DECLARE @BermudaTriangle geography = geography::STPolyFromText
('POLYGON((
    -80.190262  25.774252,
    -66.118292 18.466465,
    -64.75737 32.321384,
    -80.190262 25.774252
))', 4326)

SELECT ItemID, ReportedGPSPoint.Lat, ReportedGPSPoint.Long
FROM Items
WHERE ReportedGPSPoint.STIntersects(@BermudaTriangle) = 1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But the problem I have is how do I get the co-ordiantes from a polygon on google maps in the correct counter-clockwise order.

Comment: I'd say that would be a separate question. Post it as a separate question, use the [google-maps tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).